# Regex Password must have a letter and either a number or a symmbol, minimum of eight characters

Tags: javascript, ios, regex, swift

I am new to `iOS` development. I need to validate password using regex. Its requirement is minimum of 8 characters, must have an alphabet and either a number or a symbol.

**Here's what I have came up with so far:**

```
^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$
```

The problem is that it does not accept if the password has no number. I'm having trouble with either the number or symbol.

Comment: can you specify what kind of symbol??

Comment: @May anykind of special character

Comment: Wiktor has already answered that for you .. You just need to define your special symbol...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `(?=.*[0-9])` part in your pattern does not allow submitting a password without a digit.

Solution: expand the character class `[0-9]` Iin this lookahead that will allow submitting passwords with a digit *OR* with a "symbol".

**You must define the set of required symbols yourself**.

Say, you want to require a digit or any of these: a comma, period, hyphen. Then, use `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9.,-]).{8,}$`.

Comment: Note that `\W` matches any character other than a letter, digit or `_`. Try adding it like this: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[0-9\W]).{8,}$` (note that in Swift you need to use a double backslash: `\\W`).

Comment: your regex allows a password that doesnt contain number or symbol. What i need there must be an aplhabet and number/symbol.

Comment: Please define a *symbol* and provide some valid and invalid example input strings in the question. The regex in my answer allows a string like `abc.€¥₩%` or `abc14':;,?((&&^$#@`.